# Case Feed Object's field 'Body' is not showing up on filter - Reports

Tags: apex, reporting, custom-reports

Case Feed Object's field 'Body' is not showing up on filter - Reports..But I am able to add the field 'Body' as column on reports
[image]

Comment: What is the report type used here, Can you include report type screenshot as well ?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't filter on long text area fields. That's just a limitation of how reports/SOQL works. You can verify if a field is filterable using an Execute Anonymous script:

```
// Assertion fails, because Body is not filterable.
Assert.isTrue(FeedItem.Body.getDescribe().isFilterable());
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify if 'Encrypt chatter' is enabled in your org under Setup -> encryption policy. If so, casefeed.body field will be visible in report but not be filterable.